# Non-repeating Quartz Jobs with Crontrigger?

Tags: c#, quartz.net, crontrigger, topshelf

I have a C# Topshelf windows Service that processes Quartz Jobs. Those jobs are stored in the database, like this:

```
public class JobConfiguration : IJobConfiguration {   
   public string Name { get; set; }          //ImportService
   public string Type { get; set; }          //[ClassName, AssemblyName]
   public string CronTrigger { get; set; }   //example: 0 0 12 * * ? 
   public string CronMeaning { get; set; }   //example: fire at noon every day
}
```

Now I have to add a Job that is only fired once (all other jobs had to be repeated). My (temporary) solution is to leave the CronTrigger field NULL and start those jobs with a SimpleTrigger instead of a CronTrigger like:

```
if (JobConfiguration.CronTrigger == Null)
   //start job with Quartz SimpleTrigger
else
   //start job with Quartz CronTrigger
```

Is there a better solution to do this? In other words: is there a CronTrigger that allows you to start a job only once and never repeat it.

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to make the JobConfiguration abstract and have a SimpleJobConfiguration and CronJobConfiguration inherit from that JobConfiguration.

In the database they can be stored in the same table.

An other solution is to use the StartTimeUtc and EndTimeUtc of a trigger, both Simple and Cron. This allows you to create a cron statement that will run every 30 minutes but with an EndDateUtc on the trigger of DateTime.Now().Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(31)).